# How to generate a weak (e.g. 128-bit) RSA key?

Tags: openssl, rsa

I would like to do some testing with very weak RSA keys, like 128-bit or 256-bit to practice a little bit. But OpenSSL denies the creation of such weak keys with

```
$ openssl genrsa -out test.key 128
Error setting RSA length
40C7C155167F0000:error:1C8000AB:Provider routines:rsa_gen_set_params:key size too small:../providers/implementations/keymgmt/rsa_kmgmt.c:514:
```

I'm completely aware that such a key is about as secure as no encryption at all, because it can be factored in milliseconds, which is the whole point of the thing.

Aside from manually piecing together a weak key in a hex editor, how would you do such a thing?

Comment: You don't show any research efforts. How about googling first? "generate rsa key python github" gives many relevant examples on the first page.

Comment: I did google "generate weak rsa key" and nothing came up. In fact this came up, but it's exactly wrong. https://superuser.com/questions/890743 .

Comment: If you use OpenSSL 1.1.0 or lower it doesn't have this safety check. In general if you want to run insecure software, using software that was obsoleted because of its insecurity is a straightforward way. Be careful not to get it mixed with software that you actually trust, of course. Also note RSA-128 can only encrypt 5 bytes (with v1.5 padding, itself insecure if there's a padding oracle), and can't sign at all.

Comment: @FalcoGer just under the SuperUser result from Google is https://www.reddit.com/r/crypto/comments/f3q32x/how_to_generate_vulnerable_rsa_keys/  And if that SuperUser answer is no longer correct, did you try a version of openssl from the same timeframe as that answer? Is there a programming language that you prefer? Have you looked at that languages RSA libraries to see what limitations there might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of OpenSSL do not support `genrsa` numbits below 512.

> The default is 2048 and values less than 512 are not allowed.

I had no issue using `openssl genrsa -out rsa.key 128` with LibreSSL 3.3.6

Here's some Python code that will generate keys; modify it as needed.

**WARNING:** These keys should never be used for anything.

```
import rsa

pubkey,privkey = rsa.newkeys(128)
print(pubkey.save_pkcs1('PEM').decode('UTF-8'))
print(privkey.save_pkcs1('PEM').decode('UTF-8'))

pubkey,privkey = rsa.newkeys(256)
print(pubkey.save_pkcs1('PEM').decode('UTF-8'))
print(privkey.save_pkcs1('PEM').decode('UTF-8'))
```

**Output:**

> -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----   MBgCEQCl/IGtHk0lD0CvdwOKbFtzAgMBAAE=
> -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
>
> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----   MGICAQACEQCl/IGtHk0lD0CvdwOKbFtzAgMBAAECEHp0P8LU8PrWWHEKUcKIQxEC
> CQv3mIVsiuS4yQIIDd7BlSarTFsCCQtwCEE1XYZ/KQIIBs84/O/aI4cCCQazNJyo
> Sa762g==
> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
>
> -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----   MCgCIQC0uFXIkpfJTJNMCsc4UTHvkfUGgs1dW3r9OLEBSnNCVwIDAQAB
> -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
>
> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----   MIGsAgEAAiEAtLhVyJKXyUyTTArHOFEx75H1BoLNXVt6/TixAUpzQlcCAwEAAQIh
> AJ9X/UNJhg4Wt7WPt1K/u/mPU9MwrXCqQVIPCXLrwuoRAhIA9DxAuEES2PbGPi5k
> 0hdwvk8CEAC9bNqhV9lSmjAn7XwlAXkCEgC7HsqrIFgzWGYsT9k4yXK8qwIPRsU1
> hZQRsKfEmBZFDHpZAhEv3CG7tGSFobuQzMFxO4643A==
> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

**References**
[OpenSSL genrsa](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-genrsa.html)
[Python RSA](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/)